# Fix Flink parallelism with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm currently submitting a job using `./bin/start-cluster.sh` and `./bin/flink run -c org.example.App /home/user/flink_app.jar` that consumes messages from two kafka topics, joins them using the key, does a 15s window and then write to a kafka topic. Every kafka topic has 20 partitions.

The problem is that when I use `parallelism.default` > 1 on `flink-conf.yaml`, I stop receiving outputs. My flink job stop writing to the output kafka topic, but it shows no errors. With parallelism = 1 and numberOfTaskSlots = 1, works great.

My ideal case is to use `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 4` and `parallelism.default: 20` configurations. How do I fix my Flink job?

Answer (score 0):

With `./bin/start-cluster.sh`, you get a single Task Manager. With `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1`, your maximum parallelism will be 1. Trying to use a higher parallelism will mean that the Job Manager is waiting for more slots to become available, which never happens.

If you want to run with parallelism of 20, then you'll need to set `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 20`. Ideally you'll have at least that many cores on the server where you're running the cluster.

Comment: You recommend using `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 20` and then running the job with `./bin/start-cluster.sh`? Or do I need to use another way to submit the job?

Comment: The `./bin/start-cluster.sh` script is there to facilitate development/debugging with a local cluster. If you need to run with high parallelism, you should be using a real Flink cluster.